# Rails 4 migration not adding fields to an existing database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have an order database that I am trying to add two new fields to it

1) seller_id 
2) buyer_id

when i run the command

**rails generate migration AddFieldstoOrders buyer_id:integer seller_id:integer**

it shows

```
 invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20140414094632_add_fieldsto_orders.rb
```

after running rake dd:migrate and rails s it shows

== 20140414094632 AddFieldstoOrders: migrating ================================
== 20140414094632 AddFieldstoOrders: migrated (0.0000s) =======================

it should give me the seller_id table and buyer_id table. I have double checked the orders database model via the sqlite database model viewer and both fields have not appeared

both fields have been added to my user.rb and order.rb models

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   validates :name, presence: true

   has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :sales, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "seller_id"
   has_many :purchases, class_name: "Order", foreign_key: "buyer_id"
end
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :address, :city, :state, presence: true

    belongs_to :listing
    belongs_to :buyer, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User"
end
```

I have successfully added a listings id to the order database using 
rails generate migration AddListingIdToOrders listing_id:integer but now i am unable to add the seller_id and buyer_id fields

migration file

```
class AddFieldstoOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the actual migration file: `db/migrate/20140414094632_add_fieldsto_orders.rb`, your problem is because of the lowercase `t` on `toOrders`.

The command you should have run is:

```
rails generate migration AddFieldsToOrders buyer_id:integer seller_id:integer
```

which would hvae generated a migration file `db/migrate/20140414094632_add_fields_to_orders.rb` (note the extra underscore)

You should do the following to fix this:

```
rake db:rollback
rails generate migration AddFieldsToOrders buyer_id:integer seller_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

And then delete your original `db/migrate/20140414094632_add_fieldsto_orders.rb`
.  The rollback just takes the entry out the `schema_migrations` table in the database to make it cleaner.

Comment: yes rollback the db and ran the migration again , working now, thanks

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
rails generate migration AddFieldsToOrders buyer_id:integer seller_id:integer
```

You have AddFieldstoOrders which should be AddFieldsToOrders

So now you have two options.

**Option 1**

1. Rollback the previous migration ie rake db:rollback
2. Delete it.

Run the command again ie

```
rails generate migration AddFieldsToOrders buyer_id:integer seller_id:integer
```

**Option 2**

1. Rollback the previous migration ie rake db:rollback
2. Edit the migration ie

   add_column :orders, :buyer_id, :integer

   add_column :orders, :seller_id, :integer

Comment: thanks Mohit rolled back the db and ran the migration again , cheers!